# "Group By" Clause not working

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, group-by

I put you in context, we're doing a project with .NET and C#.
The project is linked to the following SQL Database table.

[image]

On the project, We have a *Search field* where the user can type and we filter the *textSearch* with **PROTOTYPE_CODE** field in our DB.

The thing is that we reached the point that when user type, for example, *P30*, the software filters it properly and it shows just the rows with "P30" as Code:

[image]

Now is when we have the problem, we want to have grouped the rows with the same Code (PROTOTYPE_CODE) to get a response similar and instead of two rows with "P30" just get one row with "P30" but the sum number on the *pieces* column. In this case would be something like this:

[image]

The ting is that we're not getting the way to do it as VS is giving us constnaly errors, I show you the different ways we tried.

```
 private IEnumerable<Prototypes> GetQuery()
        {
            return from search in prototypesBindingSource.DataSource as List<Prototypes>
                   where search.PROTOTYPE_CODE == (textSearch.Text) || search.PROTOTYPE_DESCR == (textSearch.Text) 
                   group search by search.PROTOTYPE_CODE into codeGroup
                   select search;
        }
```

In this case we get *"The name 'search' does not exists in the current context"  error on"* select search.

We also tried

```
Group By codice = search.PROTOTYPE_CODE
Into Classes = Group, Count();
```

Getting the same error. We tried it with different ways and never getting the expected result with this count, would be fantastic to find the correct way since we're really stucked here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement should look like this:

```
return from search in prototypesBindingSource.DataSource as List<Prototypes>
                   where search.PROTOTYPE_CODE == (textSearch.Text) || search.PROTOTYPE_DESCR == (textSearch.Text) 
                   group search by search.PROTOTYPE_CODE into codeGroup
                   select new {
    Code = codeGroup.Key,
    Count = codeGroup.Count()
};
```

Comment: It seems that it works good but now I'm getting the fields blank on search, I suppose that instead of:
`dataGridView2.DataSource = query.ToList();`
I have to add more information there?

Comment: You need to make sure that the columns in the grid view match the names of the properties in the object returned from the query. That might be the cause of the blank fields.

Comment: Well, the names are matching but I suppose there's something on DataPropertyName for example, or some similar option that has to be changed, right?

Comment: Yes. DataPropertyName must match the property name of the object returned by the query.